# Can one socket listen to multiple UDP ports?

Tags: linux, sockets, unix, udp

I want to listen on a *lot* of different UDP port numbers -- eventually up to 1,000.  It would make sense to do this with one server.  I'm pretty sure I'll need to call `socket()` 1,000 times to create 1,000 sockets (therefore 1,000 file descriptors), and then call `bind()` 1,000 times to bind each socket to a different port.  And in fact I've got this working (with ~100 port numbers, so far), but boy, is it a lot of file descriptors!

The question is, is there a better way?  (I'm pretty sure the answer is "no", but I've got to ask.)

Comment: The answer is 'no' unless you're prepared to deal in raw sockets.